# getting mutual id without intersect sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, intersection

I need a select query for getting mutual R_ID for L_IDs based on input

```
L_ID | R_ID|  
-----|-----|   
 1   |  1  |
 2   |  1  |
 3   |  1  |
 1   |  2  |
 2   |  2  |
 4   |  2  |
 2   |  3  |
 3   |  3  |
 4   |  3  |
 5   |  3  |
 ..
```

for example if I pass 1,2,3 : it returns 1

```
SELECT R_ID FROM table WHERE L_ID in (1,2,3)

R_ID |   
-----|  
 1   |
```

for example if I pass 2,3,4,5 : it returns 3

```
SELECT R_ID FROM table WHERE L_ID in (4,2,3,5)

R_ID |   
-----|  
 3   |
```

**note:** all the combinations of L_ID like (1,2,3) are unique with a common R_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`.  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT R_ID
FROM table
WHERE L_ID in (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY R_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;  -- this value is the number of matches
```

Note that an `R_ID` with 1, 2, 3, and 4 will match.  If this is undesirable, then:

```
SELECT R_ID
FROM table
GROUP BY R_ID
HAVING SUM(L_ID IN (1, 2, 3)) = 3 AND
       COUNT(*) = 3;
```